# @Transactional doesn't work in @QuarkusTest

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

Data created inside a test method is visible to other tests even when `@Transactional` annotation is used for test method or test class.

```
@QuarkusTest
@Transactional
```

Sample application is available [here](https://github.com/sudhirtumati/quarkus-sample)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer you will like but that's something we don't support right now.

Changes done in a test are not rollbacked.

I thought we had an issue for that but I couldn't find an obvious one apart from this old one when we, among other things, discuss this subject: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/461 (this comment in particular: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/461#issuecomment-457202572).

Could you create a specific issue in [our tracker](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new/choose)?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Submitted [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6463) issue in your tracker